# send auto generated email using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

How to send email (auto genarated) when user hit send button after user type email address onto text box? Any sites that I can refer? Many thanks

Comment: You should do more google. There are plenty of examples.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I just need a suggestions from any one here. Thats all :)

Answer (score 2):

You really should do more research since the answer you're looking for is easily found. However, this will point you in the right direction.

```
using System.Net.Mail;  
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("from@here.com", "to@there.com");
    mm.Subject = "some subject";
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.Body = "<span>your html goes here -- for plain text see IsBodyHtml property</span>";         
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: Why are you setting `IsBodyHtml  = true` but then setting the `Body` to some plain text? ;-)

Comment: IsBodyHtml is set to true if the message body is in Html; else false. The default is false.

Comment: for more info Google it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555813/what-does-mailmessage-isbodyhtml-do

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx

Comment: @Pushpendra I'm fully aware of what the property was for - I just thought you might want to make it clearer for the OP why you're setting it to true when OP might not want a html body!

Comment: Yes are setting IsBodyHtml = true so that whatever content you send now we don't need to change our need.

Comment: @Bridge - thanks for the nudge (and good humor) - up'd you for that