# Add link that contains space into email body

Tags: c#, ssis

I am working on a project.
Can any body tell me how can we add hyperlink that contains space in it into a mail body
through c# script.
I have tried the method as shown below

```
<file:\\networkshare\February Expense Report.xls>
```

But in the output i even get this `<>`.
I just want the path .Please help me out.
I am using ssis script task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2710511: please try to improve formatting. Parts of you question have disappeared. Read the [ask] page and [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i was using SSIS send mail task i was not allowed to add html tag inside it.
Finally i found answer:)
I just replaced space with %20.
file:\networkshare\February%20Expense%20Report.xls

Answer (score 0):

Is your email body HTML?

If yes, a link should be written as `<a href="file://networkshare/February%20Expense Report.xls">February Expense Report</a>`

1. An html link should use the `<a>` tag
2. Spaces in url can be url encoded using `%20`

Comment: email body is not of html...is there any other method ...how to use the html body inside c# code..

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555813/what-does-mailmessage-isbodyhtml-do) can help?

Comment: I put exactly the html part you should include to produce the link. What are you not getting?

Comment: For including the HTML tag that you have sent is there any thing to be included before...

Comment: You full email must be a valid html content (starts with `<html>`, have a `<body>`, etc.)

Comment: I won't be able to teach you html. Please google a bit for html email with C#. There's plenty of good tutorial.