# EMail sent using free text editor displays the text as html code as message body in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email

I have an application which allows sending `Emails` to different clients. I have used free text editor to write the draft and send the email.

All works fine but when I send the email with `free text box` content as message body sometimes the `body` is displayed as `html code` itself and not as plain text. This happens once in a while whereas most of the time message body is displayed as `plain text`.

But the risk is sometimes my clients might receive the `Email` body as `html code` instead of `plain text` which is bad.

Why this happens and how to avoid such risk??

Comment: do this to your MailMessage obj : `mailMessageObj.IsBodyHtml = false;`

Comment: Try this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555813/what-does-mailmessage-isbodyhtml-do

Comment: But as per the link given by rajeeshmenoth it says that "The key here is that if you want to send a HTML formatted message you need to use IsBodyHtml = true (default is false) to have your content rendered as HTML." This means that mailMessage obj must be set to true mailMessageObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
But abhishek asked me to set it false.
What is to be done?

Comment: I have already set IsBodyHtml = true but it sometimes do read or displays the message with html tags