# c# - Email as HTML not working

Tags: c#, html, email

I have the following code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(Properties.Settings.Default.smtpServer);
mail.From = new MailAddress(Properties.Settings.Default.mailFrom);
mail.To.Add(mailto);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CC)) {
 mail.CC.Add(CC);
};
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = body;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
mail.To.Add(mailto);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = Properties.Settings.Default.SSL;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Port = Properties.Settings.Default.smtpPort;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.Username,     Properties.Settings.Default.emailPassword);
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.Timeout = 200000;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
markEmailAsSent(uid);
```

I am trying to send the below as HTML but the email isn't  being sent as so, I receive the raw html back. I have included `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`So I'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

And here is the contents of the message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Trilogy</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #F33621}
.style4 {font-family: Arial}
.style6 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #A2A2A2;
}
.style7 {
    font-family: "Agency FB";
    color: #FFAF9A;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
}
.style8 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
.style9 {
    font-size: 11pt
}
.header {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p align="left" class="style8">bla bla bla bla bla<br />
  <br />
<strong>Sometext</strong>
<br />t: 01666 666 666
<br />e: <a href="mailto:abc@123.net%</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does `body` look like in code

Comment: `mailto` is missing a quote btw

Comment: Use an `AlternateView` E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555813/what-does-mailmessage-isbodyhtml-do

Comment: (Gmail kills the head element for html email so you will lose your `<style>`)

Comment: @Azola the body is exactly as the html is in the question

Comment: @AlexK not using Gmail

Comment: I meant any email received by *@gmail.com willl arrive with no style element

Answer (score 0):

Change the html to:

```
<html> <head> <title>Trilogy</title> <style type="text/css"> </style> </head> <body> <p align="left" class="style8">bla bla bla bla bla<br />   <br /> <strong>Sometext</strong> <br />t: 01666 666 666 <br />e: <a href="mailto:abc@123.net"</a></p>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this should be enough:

```
<p align="left" class="style8">bla bla bla bla bla<br />
<br />
<strong>Sometext</strong>
<br />t: 01666 666 666
<br />e: <a href="mailto:abc@123.net"</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with big HTML file.

```cs
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail));
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
mail.Body = message;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Port = smtpPort;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPass);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = smtpEnableSsl;

smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Host = smtpHost;
try
{
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
    log.LogInformation("SUCCESS sent a mail for SUBSCRIPTION - " + tableData.subscription + " and SUBSCRIPTION_ID - " + tableData.subscriptionId);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
    log.LogInformation("ERROR -  Unable to send a mail for SUBSCRIPTION - "+ tableData.subscription +" and SUBSCRIPTION_ID - "+tableData.subscriptionId);
}
```